# Firebase auth mobile verification stops to work when I update the version of it

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

I have been using firebase auth and firestore. I used:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
```

Now since I wanted to use firestorm's array union I had to update my firestore version to 17.0.5 or above. it didn't work.
so I changed

```
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

to

```
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

and I made

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
```

now The app works but my mobile verification doesn't. if I make the version 11.8.0 it will work again. I Really need both array union of firestore and mobile auth of fireauth to work. I could use some help since I tried literally every version combination of firestore and auth. Thank you
error log:

```
2019-07-23 14:13:24.919 735-735/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
```

2019-07-23 14:13:24.919 735-735/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-07-23 14:13:24.919 735-735/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-07-23 14:13:24.920 1168-1337/? E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: -1, Chload: -1
2019-07-23 14:13:26.227 735-735/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-07-23 14:13:26.228 735-735/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-07-23 14:13:26.228 735-735/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-07-23 14:13:26.228 1168-1337/? E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: -1, Chload: -1
2019-07-23 14:13:26.230 735-735/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-07-23 14:13:26.230 735-735/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-07-23 14:13:26.230 735-735/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-07-23 14:13:27.082 21632-9900/? E/Volley: [65982] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyCa3quJDGHxhGCHz9VVUbwbM--vTTjvwJ0
2019-07-23 14:13:27.169 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.169 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.193 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.193 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.285 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.285 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.299 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.299 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.315 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.315 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.338 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.338 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.351 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.352 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.367 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.367 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.390 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.391 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.514 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.514 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.539 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.539 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.667 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.668 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.823 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.824 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.848 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.849 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.859 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.859 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.902 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.902 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.917 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.917 21632-20185/? E/asset: createFromFile(): lock file /data/resource-cache/system@emui@base@overlay@frameworkhwexthonor@frameworkhwexthonor.apk@idmap.
2019-07-23 14:13:27.929 667-667/? E/WifiHAL: enter wifi_get_link_stats

Comment: If something isn't working the way you expect, please give full details about your observations.  It's not sufficient to say "it doesn't work".  What exactly doesn't work? A certain API call?  What error does it generate?  Is there an error in your app logs?  Please edit the question and be as specific as you can.

Comment: there's no error generated else I could show you. basically I sign in using mobile auth and it doesn't send the code to me

Comment: I used the phone auth testing number too but it shows code is wrong

Comment: but if I Change my firebase auth version to 11.8.0 it works just fine

Comment: Have you updated gradle? As the new versions of Firebase needs it.

Comment: @markharrop yes it is updated

Comment: I was having problems with Firebase auth.  I updated gradle and migrated to Android x fixed the issue

Comment: Done but still didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I also get the issue like this, I changed versions.

In project Gradle file

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

And in app-level Gradle

```
firebase-core:16.0.6
firebase-auth:16.1.0
firebase-firestore:17.1.4
```

It worked perfectly fine for me.

> (You need to specify the [Gradle plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) according to your android studio version(my version is 3.4) in gradle-wrapper.properties and top-level Gradle)

Try these versions and let me know. Hope it will help!

Comment: Still not able to authenticate

Comment: grade plugin version is 3.4.2 and Gradle version is 5.1.1

Comment: Still, you get the same errors? can I see your error logs?